# Pygame - Unable to put an entire text in different lines

Tags: python, pygame

I have an input box in which text is put to be rendered. However, if the text exceeds a certain length, I want it to be displayed in different lines.

I had some code that looks like this:

```
 def scale_box(self, screen, text):
        max_length = 10
        nb_lines = int(len(text) / max_length)
        index = 0
        self.box.y -= nb_lines * self.coords[3]
        self.box.h *= nb_lines
        y = self.box.y
        for i in range(0, nb_lines + 1):
            line = text[index: index + max_length]
            index += max_length
            Line = self.box_font.render(line, True, self.font_color)
            screen.blit(Line, (self.box.x + 10, y))
            y += self.coords[3]
```

So, the size (dimensions) of the input box is updated depending on the length of the text.
This method is called when a certain event occurs.

And somewhere in the "main" code

```
    screen.blit(self.text_box, (self.box.x + 10, self.box.y + 10))
```

For example, if the text = 'Something written here...'.
I want to get something like this:

```
Something 
written he
re...
```

But I get only the last line:

```
re...
```

Comment: self.text_box is the text within the input box. Yeah normally that what it does

Comment: So if  `scale_box` draws the texte to the screen, then what is `screen.blit(self.text_box, (self.box.x + 10, self.box.y + 10))` intended to do?

Comment: `screen.blit(self.text_box, (self.box.x + 10, self.box.y + 10))`   renders the text constantly but the method is called only when the "return"  key is pressed

Comment: So `screen.blit(self.text_box, (self.box.x + 10, self.box.y + 10))` renders the text in one line and `scale_box` renders multiple lines

Comment: It is strange but is done this way to use it for 2 different things. One for the what the user enters manually (on the keyboard) which explains ` screen.blit(self.text_box, (self.box.x + 10, self.box.y + 10))` and the other is for answering. But as the answer needs sometimes to stand on more than one line, so I need a method that displays the text in different lines depending on the length of the answer

Comment: The answer which is represented in the method by "text" is chosen from a list of "answers" that have different lengths

Answer (score 1):

The calculation of the number of lines is wrong. The number of lines is the integral part of the division `len(text) // max_length + 1`, except there the text has a length with is exactly a multiple of the number of lines. This means `+1` has to be done if the remainder `len(text) % max_length` is greater 0:

```py
nb_lines = len(text) // max_length + (1 if len(text) % max_length > 0 else 0)
```

Split the text and render it to a list of surfaces:

```py
lines = []
for i in range(nb_lines):
    linetext = text[i*max_length : (i+1)*max_length]
    lines.append( self.box_font.render(linetext, True, self.font_color) )
```

Calculate the width and the height of the text block, shift and update athe text box:

```py
width = max([l.get_width() for l in lines])
height = sum([l.get_height() for l in lines])
y = self.box.y - nb_lines * self.coords[3]

self.box = pygame.Rect(self.box.x, y, width, height)
```

Finally `blit` the text to the `screen`, line by line:

```
y = self.box.y
for l in lines:
    screen.blit(l, (self.box.x + 10, y))  
    y += l.get_height()
```

The full function may look like this:

```py
def scale_box(self, screen, text):

    max_length = 10
    nb_lines = len(text) // max_length + (1 if len(text) % max_length > 0 else 0)
    lines = []
    for i in range(nb_lines):
        linetext = text[i*max_length : (i+1)*max_length]
        lines.append( self.box_font.render(linetext, True, self.font_color) )

    width = max([l.get_width() for l in lines])
    height = sum([l.get_height() for l in lines])
    y = self.box.y - nb_lines * self.coords[3]
    self.box = pygame.Rect(self.box.x, y, width, height)

    y = self.box.y
    for l in lines:
        screen.blit(l, (self.box.x + 10, y))  
        y += l.get_height()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try it.

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't render the right text which is in the list 'lines'. It always prints the same text I put before on it  (at the beginning)

Comment: I have a class for input box in general. I used it to display two boxes on the screen. One for the user and the other for the answer. For the user, the box isn't resized because I have limited it to be displayed on only one line. So for the this box there's no problem. The problem is with the answer box. Before the user starts to write anything on his box, a 'text' (or a message) that is "Ask your question" is written in the answer box. Then when the user asks for a question and press "enter" (here is the event where I _call scale_box_).

Comment: According to the user's question, an answer is chosen from a list. This list is composed of many answers of different lengths. But now, it prints only the first message "Ask your question" in the answer's box. The problem is not comming from your answer but from my code.

Comment: Yes. It is to shift the box a bit higher than where it was. `self.coords[3]` is the list that represents the coordinates of the input box (0->x, 1->y, 2->w, 3->h). But I should have `self.box.y -= (nb_lines - 1) * self.coords[3]` and not `self.box.y -= nb_lines * self.coords[3]`

Comment: @Yasmine I add `y = self.box.y - nb_lines * self.coords[3]` to the answer.

Comment: I upvote your answer because it will works for others. My problem is that the message I put at the first "Ask your question " is still displayed  (in the place of the text contained in the list "lines").

Comment: @YasmineIt is impossible to find the issue without seeing the code and a screenshot of the issue. All I can do is to guess, but that won't make any sense at all.

Comment: Yeah I understand. Thank you for your help  :)